# Hard Drive: I can see it in /Volumes, but it does not show up in Finder

Tags: finder, hard-drive, external-disk, ntfs

I'm connecting my external Hard Drive on my Mac. It's a NTFS drive. It used to show up normally on Finder's sidebar and Desktop as well, but it doesn't anymore.

**But it does show up in /Volumes folder. I can see all the folder and go through.**

So, here what I tried:

**1)** `diskutil list` lists my external drive:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS LUCAS                   1.0 TB     disk2s1
```

---

**2)** `GetFileInfo /Volumes/LUCAS` does not have the capital letter V (means it's **not** invisible).

---

**3)** Whenever I connect the HD, it gives me two weird messages on console:

> mds[62]: (Volume.Normal:166) vsd:0x7fe0b30a2200 DisabledStore recycle:6
>   context:{
>      DisabledRecycleCount = 6;
>   }

and

> mds[62]: (Volume.Error:577) vsd:0x7fe0b397d000 Open failed.  failureCount:6 {
>      DisabledRecycleCount = 6;
>   }

---

**4)** Yep, I also tried the `chflags nohidden /Volumes/LUCAS`. No luck.

---

So, what can I do? I can browse the drive, but it just doesn't mount. That's all.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your "2)" attempt to fix it. `mds` is the process that helps Spotlight works.

Comment: @IronCraftMan If GetFileInfo <item> shows ...v... invisibility of the item is turned **off** and respectively ...V... invisibility is turned **on**

Comment: In Finder preferences, under General, is "Hard disks" or "External disks" (depending on how it sees your drive) turned on? How about the same option under the Sidebar pane?

Comment: @timothymh Yes, it's all set.

Comment: Does it show up in Disk Utility?

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yes, as I said in **1)**

Comment: @LucasVeiga not in diskutil, but in the actual GUI.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yes, also on actual GUI. It works normal, it just doesn't mount on desktop or Finder's sidebar.

Comment: @LucasVeiga are you using any special software to use NTFS formatted drives?

Comment: I was using Paragon in trial mode, but it's trial evaluated. In fact, now you said, this problem just show up after the trial ended.

Comment: @IronCraftMan I was using Paragon.

Comment: @LucasVeiga and there's your issue. Please include those details (The software, and that the trial ended). Please remove paragon and restart. Then plug in your drive and see what happens

Comment: @IronCraftMan Done. Removed. Restarted. Nothing yet.